# NSSortDescriptor not sorting NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I've been stuck on this for a little while now and I'm bringing it here for help.  For some reason I cannot get `NSSortDescriptor` to sort an array of data after a fetch request.  Below is the code for the request:

```
+ (NSArray *)retrieveCommentsOfPost:(Post *) post withLimit:(int) limit
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context        = [self appDelegate].managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest         *request        = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSSortDescriptor       *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];

    //    request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    request.fetchLimit = limit;
    request.entity     = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Comment" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"post = %@", post];

    NSLog(@"post: %@", post);

    NSError *executeFetchError = nil;
    NSArray *result            = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&executeFetchError];

    return result;
}
```

The returned result seems to be ignoring the `sortDescriptor` all together, and I'm not sure what needs to happen in order for it to work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: Update:  It appears that the NSSortDescriptor is actually working, but it's getting ignored elsewhere in code:

```
-(void) loadTableData{
[[PaperbackServiceClient sharedInstance]retrieveCommentsOnPost:[self.post.post_id longValue] WithBlock:^(BOOL success, id json) {
    if(success){
        _comments = json;

        NSLog(@"COMMENTS JSON: %@", json);

        // year-mo-da 00:00:00 + 0000

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

On the `loadTableData` method the JSON was not maintaining the order of the original call, so I placed the `NSSortDescriptor` in the `loadTableData` method instead:

```
-(void) loadTableData{
[[PaperbackServiceClient sharedInstance]retrieveCommentsOnPost:[self.post.post_id longValue] WithBlock:^(BOOL success, id json) {
    if(success){

        NSSortDescriptor       *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];

        _comments = [json sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
        NSLog(@"COMMENTS JSON: %@", json);

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
}
```